# Alternative formulas for vba script

Tags: excel, vba

I made a VBA function which turns my raw data into a table format since I want to use a pivottable for charts. The problem is that my file need to run on excel online and VBA is not running in a cloud environment. 
Is there a way to do this with functions/power query/...
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Or use Office-JS.

Comment: Wow that changes the game and is a bit over my head. Tried searching for it but if I understand correctly you need like VS to write the code or if you're a 365 insider you can use script lab? If I share this on sharepoint van other users then also use the code I wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a while but i managed. It is in fact Excel online compatible Each formula is displayed above the corresponding column. I added some data to make sure it could handle extra data.
=IF(F8<>"",ROWS($G$7:G7),NA#)
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G$8:$G$32,ROWS($G$7:G7))
=IF(ISNUMBER(H8),IF(ISTEXT(INDEX($B$6:$C$32,H8,1)),INDEX($B$6:$C$32,H8,2),I7),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(H8),IF(ISTEXT(INDEX($C$7:$D$32,H8,1)),INDEX($C$7:$D$32,H8,2),J7),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(H8),INDEX(E$8:E$32,$H8),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(H8),INDEX(F$8:F$32,$H8),"")

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have to make the formulas myself step by step to understand how you came to that solution but this is exactly what I wanted.